# rpy2 module not working in Python3.2

Tags: r, module, python-3.x, importerror, rpy2

I am trying to import the rpy2 (version2.3.4) library into Python (version3.2.3) on a Ubuntu 12.10 machine. The rpy2 documentation says that rpy2 works under all Python 3 versions and I am also finding other topics related to rpy2 and Python3.2 which show that these versions should work together. Anyhow when I try to import a module:

```
from rpy2 import robjects
```

the result is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/rpy2/robjects/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    import rpy2.rinterface as rinterface
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError("Python (>=2.7 and < 3.0) or >=3.3 are required to run rpy2")
RuntimeError: Python (>=2.7 and < 3.0) or >=3.3 are required to run rpy2
```

So, is rpy2 really not working with Python3.2 what would fit to the information the projects is giving me or waht might be the problem.

thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The rpy2 documentation says that rpy2 works under all Python 3 versions

Not quite, I hope; check the part about [installing rpy2](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.3/html/overview.html#installation).

Python 3.2 will probably never be supported by rpy2 (Python 3.2 is already EOL). If your are after using Python 3, update to Python 3.3.

Comment: Thx. With your link I noticed that I was in the documentation of rpy2 2.2.1. Sorry for the inconvenience.